# firewalld: Block non-ESP packets on interface in GNU/Linux similar to OpenBSD

Tags: ipsec, iptables

I am trying to "enforce" IPSec (StrongSwan) traffic on openSUSE.
On OpenBSD, with the IKE daemon `iked` and the packet filter `pf`, I employ a ruleset like the following, to ensure only encapsulated traffic passes the interface, practically blocking all traffic should the tunnel be down:

```
block on vio1
block on enc0

pass in on vio1 proto udp from 10.1.1.2 to 10.1.0.2 \
port {500, 4500}
pass out on vio1 proto udp from 10.1.0.2 to 10.1.1.2 \
port {500, 4500}

pass in on vio1 proto esp from 10.1.1.2 to 10.1.0.2
pass out on vio1 proto esp from 10.1.0.2 to 10.1.1.2

pass in on enc0 from 10.1.1.2 to 10.1.0.2 \
keep state (if-bound)
pass out on enc0 from 10.1.0.2 to 10.1.1.2 \
keep state (if-bound)
```

I was unable to locate instructions on how to employ such a ruleset in firewalld based GNU/Linux systems, but might have been looking for the wrong terms.
If possible, I would like to use native firewalld commands, however should these not suffice for capturing ESP packets, I assume "rich" rules could be employed just as well.

Would appreciate any help.